# How to remove the ground or extract human from a 3d scene

Tags: python, mesh, objects, scene

I have a model shown below, and it is built by 3d reconstruction technology. I want to know if there's a way to extract the human or delete the ground from this scene so that I can rig the human model.
[image]

Comment: If the gorund and the character are the same object, you need to switch to Edit mode, select the faces that you want to delete and X > Delete Faces. That said, if the character is high-poly, it's not recommended to rig it, you should better retopologize

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly what you mentioned, but I just find it time-consuming, so I wonder if there is a better way, like using the script?

Comment: I found a solution called PCL plane fitting, which works fine in my situation.

Comment: It should be pretty quick, not sure why it took time for you, maybe you needed to activate the X-Ray option (Alt Z)?

Answer (score 0):

You just use one of the selectors while in wireframe view, select vertices you don't want and then delete them.

Comment: Hello, a beck.. thanks for your contribution! This answer could really do with an illustration of exactly what you mean, perhaps played out on a simplified, 'toy' example.